# Create bubbles on a map

Tags: dictionary, math

I have a project to produce a live map. I have a map of an area and require a way to link it to an excel database.

The database produces distances which will form a bubble around a building. Showing a no go zone.

I’m looking to draw the information from the excel database and display the bubble on the map. But if the distance changes the map with alter to show it.

I’m flat out stuck and really need a bit of help.

Thank you!!

Daz

Comment: Hello. Can you help us giving the language, what have you tried and what are you errors etc. Thanks

Comment: I haven’t worked out how to link the two and develop it further. I’m aware it’s possible but unsure where to start!

Comment: @DazWright I you haven't done anything yet (not selected a language, no code, no libraries) and your are looking for advice on how to tackle this big project, then it is out of scope for Stack Overflow. SO is for specific programming questions (e.g., "This small snippet of code doesn't work as expected"), not for consulting. Google some keywords, and try to find other similar projects, open source or not to get some ideas to start.